# only 1 file is ever executed under my tests/ folder for TestCafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have multiple `test_*.js` files underneath a `/testcafe/tests/`folder.  When executing TestCafe from commandline OR via Visual Studio, only ONE file is ever executed....why would that be?

- tests (folder)

  - test_somefilename.js
  - test_someOtherfilename.js
  - test_onlyfileexecuted.js
  - test_anotherfilename.js

When running the following command, only 1 of the files is **ever** executed:

```
testcafe <pathToTestFolder>/tests/*.js
```

this will **only** ever execute the file named `test_onlyfileexecuted.js`

WHY?  I can manually type in the command to execute every single file and TestCafe works perfectly, but when doing glob pattern, that is the only tests found/executed....So Confused

Comment: It's a long shot, but is it really testcafe? Glob patterns are a feature of bash etc., perhaps it's your command-line environment somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run `testcafe {browser} <pathToTestFolder>/tests/` (no *.js) and Testcafe will automatically pick up all the tests in that directory

Comment: I also had an issue in Visual Studio debug that was not identifying tests due to .skip/.only being on some tests....so I removed those and we are good!  Thanks

Comment: oh, I just had `.only` on one of my fixtures without releasing it, thanks for this comment @TallKU